# how to render a data table from XML file in codeIgniter?

Tags: xml, codeigniter, datatable

I am new in codeIgniter.

I want to render a data table from an external XML file.

Suppose I have an external xml file which is having

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<defect-data xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <record>
        <DefectID>40580</DefectID>
        <Status>Open</Status>
        <DetectedOn>42110</DetectedOn>
        <AssignedTo>Bimal kumar</AssignedTo>
        <AssignedToCTSOff>Amit</AssignedToCTSOff>
    </record>
    <record>
        <DefectID>41580</DefectID>
        <Status>Close</Status>
        <DetectedOn>42110</DetectedOn>
        <AssignedTo>eve ram</AssignedTo>
        <AssignedToCTSOff>Sourav</AssignedToCTSOff>
    </record>
</defect-data>
```

I want to render this XML in html data table.

Is there any readymade way in codeIgniter to achieve this?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

No.  CodeIgniter provides help with converting strings into XML safe strings, but nothing for parsing it the other way round.

However, PHP does have [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) which can be used to parse XML for you to use.  You can use that within CodeIgniter to manipulate the XML as you need.